# Reactor Kafka - Bottleneck if the number of consumer is greater than the number of partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactor-kafka

Is the number of partitions is a bottleneck to performance if the number of kafka consumer is (much) greater than the number of partitions?

Let's say I have a topic named the-topic with only three partitions.

Now, I have this below app in order to consume from the topic:

```
@Service
public class MyConsumer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver;


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        myConsumer().subscribe();
    }

    public Flux<String> myConsumer() {
        return kafkaReceiver.receive()
                .flatMap(oneMessage -> consume(oneMessage))
                .doOnNext(abc -> System.out.println("successfully consumed {}={}" + abc))
                .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("something bad happened while consuming : {}" + throwable.getMessage()));
    }

    private Mono<String> consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> oneMessage) {
        // this first line is a heavy in memory computation which transforms the incoming message to a data to be saved.
        // it is very intensive computation, but has been tested NON BLOCKING by different tools, and takes 1 second :D
        String transformedStringCPUIntensiveNonButNonBLocking = transformDataNonBlockingWithIntensiveOperation(oneMessage);
        //then, just saved the correct transformed data into any REACTIVE repository :)
        return myReactiveRepository.save(transformedStringCPUIntensiveNonButNonBLocking);
    }

}
```

I dockerized the app and deploy in Kubernetes.

With cloud providers, I am able to easily deploy 60 of those containers, 60 of those apps.

And suppose for the sake of this question, each of my app are super resilient, never crashes.

Does it mean, since the topic has only three partitions, that at any time, 57 other consumers will be wasted?

How to benefit from scaling up the number of containers when the number of partitions is low?

Comment: Why would you need 60 consumers? What's the logic behind this. Increasing the number of partitions increases the throughput but also has some downfalls such as increased downtime when there is a new leader election.

You currently have 3 partitions and if there are 60 consumers then majority of those consumers will be inactive. Usually you should have as many consumers as partitions

Answer (score 1):

> since the topic has only three partitions, that at any time, 57 other consumers will be wasted?

Yes. That's how Kafka consumer API works. The framework you use around it isn't relevant.

> benefits from scaling up the number of containers when the number of partitions is low

You need to separate the event processing (saving to a reposistory) from the actual consumption / poll loop. For example, push transformed events onto a non-blocking, external queue / external API, without waiting for a response. Then setup an autoscaler on that API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for the answer. Thank you for confirming the waste of resource, upvoted. Before I accept, I would like to ask for some clarifications on the second part of your answer please. If you look at my snippet, ```.flatMap(oneMessage -> consume(oneMessage))``` + ```private Mono<String> consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> oneMessage) ``` the event processing (saving to a repository) as well as the transformation of event is already NON-blocking. Can the reactor core / event loop "separate the event processing" already, without me relying to external API?

Comment: It's not decoupled, though. You're waiting on the result of the save method before the function ends and processes the next event. Then your doOnNext / doOnError are blocking calls to print to IO streams

Comment: Understood. For the save method, I use ReactiveCassandraRepository, and tested trying to insert a very consequent data. I timed and used BlockHound, I believe it is non blocking. Will double check. As for the doOnNext / doOnError, I am using an async LOGGER. But again, let me double check

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean, since the topic has only three partitions, that at any time, 57 other consumers will be wasted?

Yes. For a single consumer group you can have as many concurrent consumers as the number of partitions.

> How to benefit from scaling up the number of containers when the number of partitions is low please?

You might try to register each of those containers in different consumer groups of number of partitions. That will work. But as mentioned by @OneCricketeer you should have a separate event processing pipeline. That would be the best approach if you don't want to process the same event multiple times.

Comment: Separate consumer group wouldn't work well here since that would duplicate data in what appears to be a database save action

Comment: Yes multiple consumer groups would be reading the same data multiple times. However when adding to the db, one can check if data is already saved to the db and if it is then don't save.

Comment: Also one can try something like, one consumer group reads from even offset and others from odd offset. That would save the extra call to db to check if it's already processed or not.

Comment: That's not how Kafka consumer groups work. Offsets are read in sequence, not selectively

Comment: I'm not saying we have to read offsets selectively, but when the consumer consumes a message from a partition of a topic, it can skip the message of an odd or even offset in a partition based on the consumer group its in. I believe the api can provide the offset of the message. Other consumer group can continue with the leftover offsets as offsets are maintained per consumer group I believe.

Comment: Incorrect. Only one consumer can be assigned a partition at a time. Therefore, if you filter based on offset, you are skipping events, not making another in the group process it.